# Cannot resolve "org.eclipse.swt" in eclipse photon

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I want to move my RCP appplication from eclipse oxygen to the latest eclipse version.

So i downloaded eclipse photon and installed all needed libaries and some more.
Then i imported my RCP application project plugins.
Eclispe compile the projects and mark issues that he cannot resolve "org.eclise.swt".

All class that i need are in the "org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.106.0.v20170608-0516.jar" but i cannot add this to my dependencies in my manifest.

Comment: The dependency should just be `org.eclipse.swt` this hasn't changed in Photon

Comment: The dependency is org.eclispe.swt but eclipse cannot resolve it.

Comment: Possibly some problem in your target platform. I moved several workspaces from Oxygen to Photon recently with no problems.

Comment: So now i set directly the "org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.106.0.v20170608-0516.jar" in the Build Path. The effect that i generate is now that i have this swt.jar as Referenced Libary. After that i fixed the rest of the compiling issues and configure the content of the application.product. Now my application wants to start but the loading of the first swt class failed.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:144) ... Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.14.200.v20180516-2019 ...

Comment: For plugins putting things directly in the project build path will not work, dependencies must be listed in the MANIFEST.MF Require-Bundle. Something is wrong with your setup, there should be no problem finding the org.eclipse.swt plugin. Look at your Target Platform and check that it contains SWT (among many other things).

Comment: I have no idea what is wrong in my Target Platform.
I installed this eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/photonm6
I updated the RCP functions via the install function in eclipse but i still get the issue that eclipse cannot resolve org.eclispe.swt.
In the plugin folder of ecipse is the correct swt libary and also when i check the click on properties on the org.eclipse.swt dependency i get the match with the swt labary that is in my Target Platform but why it doesn't compile?

Comment: I solved my compile issue.
I make a new install of eclipse so i installed the JEE eclipse version and add the RCP part via the udaptesite mechanismus.